# certain characters get converted when adding to file

Tags: debian, character-encoding

I have a script I am writing, that includes passing across a connection string to socat.

When I paste this into the command line it is fine, but when I open a file and paste it into there (`pico filename.sh`), the characters are converted to something else, and the connection string fails.

The code in question is:

```
conTest=$(echo -e -n "@\0\0'{abcde\0fghij\0Ç\x01Ó|" | socat STDIO tcp4:127.0.0.1:12345)
```

The characters with an issue are:

```
0Ç\x01Ó
```

which get converted to:

```
0ï¿½\x01ï¿½
```

Is there a way to stop them being converted?

I am connecting to this machine (Debian) using putty (ssh) from my Windows 7 PC.

My initial text is in a file in notepad++ on my Windows PC. I then copy / paste it from there into the command line on my Debian Server.
When I run this it works fine.

If I open a file using pico `pico test1.sh` and copy / paste the text in, then it appears to be ok. But as soon as I try and save it (ctrl-O) the characters change.

If I then run `file test1.sh` it says `test1.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ISO-8859 text executable`.

If I run `iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-8 test1.sh` I get `illegal input sequence at position 263` which is the `Ç` character.

If I try it with nano `nano test2.sh` then the copy / paste doesn't work and I get additional characters after the problem characters. Again, as soon as I try and save it, the same happens (the characters change).

Next I tried to copy the file across using sftp. I copied it as test3.sh, and then once on the server I opened it with vi using `vi test3.sh`. This showed the same problem in that the *problem* characters got replaced.

However, running `file test3.sh` gave me `test3.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable`

I copied the file back via sftp and opened it on my windows pc, and the characters are all fine, suggetsing that the sftp process isn't a problem.

Comment: Apparently, your pico can't deal with non-ASCII characters. Is there any specific reason you need to use that editor? Have you tried changing your font to a UTF-8 font?

Comment: there's no reason, it's just what I am used to. I kind of presumed that if it worked on the command line, it would work elsewhere...

Comment: nah, it depends on the program you're using. Did you try changing the font?

Comment: I tried setting `:set encoding=utf8` in `vi` (I couldn't see how to change it in `pico`), but it made no difference. As soon as I open the file, the characters are converted.

Comment: Well, `pico` really is quite limited. Have you tried `nano`? It's basically an enhanced version of pico and should be installed by default. Although, that said, both `pico` and `nano` can read a file with `0Ç\x01Ó` correctly on my system. What is the output of running `file filename.sh`? Is the file's encoding UTF8?

Comment: so, I upload the file from my Windows PC (sftp), (and then download it to confirm sftp hasn't corrupted it) and I run `file test1.sh`. It says `Bourne-Again shell script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable`. I open it (`nano test1.sh`) and the characters are wrong. I paste the correct characters and save the file, I run `file test2,sh` and get `Bourne-Again shell script, Non-ISO extended-ASCII text executable`

Comment: Ah, now er're getting somewhere. Please [edit] your question and include this information. It looks like `nano` is not respecting the file's encoding. Also include in your question what happens if you then run `iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-8 file`. Finally, explain how you connect to this machine, mention the fact that the file comes from Windows through FTP and also tell us if using `nano`/`pico` is essential and if you get the same issue with more complete editors like `vim` or `emacs`.

Comment: OK cheers, I have expanded my question with the additional info.